# Фильтрация "с" и "до" по дате в GridView в Yii2

Tags: yii2, view, gridview, pjax

Здравствуйте. Решил сделать фильтр по дате "с" и "до" какой-то даты.

Использую жирную загрузку из бд. Код контроллера:

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $sales = Sale::find()->with('saleItems')->where(['status' => Sale::STATUS_PAYED]);

    return $this->render('index',
        [
            'sales' => $sales
        ]);
}
```

Во вью такой код (для примера):

```
echo \yii\grid\GridView::widget(['dataProvider' => new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $sales]),

'columns' => [
    ['class' => \yii\grid\SerialColumn::className()],
    'applied_at:date'
   ]
  ]);
```

Предлагаю использовать дата пикер с Pjax запросами.

Вью будет иметь вид:

```
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;

\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin();
 echo DatePicker::widget([
'name' => 'from_date',
'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
'name2' => 'to_date',
'pluginOptions' => [
    'autoclose'=>true,
    'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy'
]
]);

echo \yii\grid\GridView::widget(['dataProvider' => new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $sales]),

'columns' => [
    ['class' => \yii\grid\SerialColumn::className()],
    'applied_at:date',
]
]);
\yii\widgets\Pjax::end();
```

Добавил в модель публичные переменные

```
public $from_date;
public $to_date;
```

и валидацию для них.

Как сделать так, чтобы теперь выводил данные в пределах, которые передает виджет датапикер?

Может есть другое более логичное и лучшее решение?

Обязательно нужно, чтобы выбор периода с какую по какую дату был отдельно,а не встроен в саму таблицу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать отдельную форму, которая будет принимать, валидировать и отдавать `ActiveDataProvider`.

В контроллере работать только с формой.

**Форма**

```
class MyForm extends Model {
    public $fromDate;
    public $toDate;

    public function rules() : array
    {
        return [
            [['fromDate', 'toDate'], 'date'],
        ];
    }

    public function search() {
        $query = Sale::find()
            ->with('saleItems')
            ->where(['status' => Sale::STATUS_PAYED]);

        if ($this->validate()) {
            $query
                ->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'applied_at', $this->fromDate])
                ->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'applied_at', $this->toDate]);
        }

        return new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]);
        }
}
```

**Контроллер**

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $form = new MyForm();
    $form->load(\Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());
    return $this->render('index', [
        'form' => $form,
        'dataProvider' => $form->search(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, за ответ. Он помог. )

Comment: Так. Ещё не понял немного про вью. 
Как она должна выглядеть?

Comment: Практически так же. Только с небольшими изменениями. В моей реализации во `view` уже передается `dataProvider` ну и поменять название полей `name` и `name2`  в `DatePicker` или в форме, тут уже какой у вас стиль написание кода. К сожалению с `DatePicker` никогда не работал

Comment: Все. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

View:

```
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;

\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin();

echo Html::beginForm();
echo DatePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'from_date',
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
    'name2' => 'to_date',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    ]
]);
echo Html::submitButton();
echo Html::endForm();

echo \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $sales]),
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => \yii\grid\SerialColumn::className()],
        'applied_at:date',
    ]
]);
\yii\widgets\Pjax::end();
```

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $fromDate = Yii::$app->request->post('from_date');
    $toDate = Yii::$app->request->post('to_date');
    $sales = Sale::find()
        ->with('saleItems')
        ->where(['status' => Sale::STATUS_PAYED])
        ->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'applied_at', $fromDate ? strtotime($fromDate . ' 00:00:00') : null])
        ->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'applied_at', $toDate ? strtotime($toDate . ' 23:59:59') : null]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'sales' => $sales
    ]);
}
```

Из модели можно убрать добавленные переменные. И можно сделать отдельную форму для валидации этих переменных либо валидировать их прямо в контроллере.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. 
Тут второй ответ, по сути, тоже самое, только с формой. Я отдам ему верный ответ, т.к. у него меньше баллов. Вы не будете против? Но спасибо большое. )

Comment: @Anatoliy.CHA да конечно, у него и ответ правильнее, а мне лень было писать код с формой))